# Setting properties or selecting from ksql returns various errors

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm working with Kakfa as the backbone of a system I'm creating, having data being able to be streamed into it mostly from a database and having aspects of it pushed into different topics, to be consumed by custom software, or sinked into another system using Kafka Connect plugings.

### Setup

What I've been able to do, is using the Postgres Source CDC from Debezium. I've had success in watching a table and having it stream data into a topic, we'll call this topic `postgres-db-table`. The schema for this is quiet complex to simply place into Redis for caching.

I've been following this example to assist me into accomplishing this:
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/tutorials/materialized/

Though I've been having some major problems with no luck in finding a work around.

### Issue

The main problem I've been finding is setting when a stream starts up, what should their offset be. Normally in the example as seen, you simply run a command in KSQL of `SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';` but this is where I'm having the issue. When I attempt this I get the following:

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
Path not found. Path='/is_valid_property/auto.offset.reset'. Check your ksql http url to make sure you are connecting to a ksql server.
```

When running the command `LIST PROPERTIES;` it doesnt come up in the drop down as an option to set.

I went ahead and created a stream by running :

```sql
CREATE STREAM "stream-postgres-table" WITH (kafka_topic='postgres-db-table', value_format='AVRO');
```

and this succeeds with no problem, but in trying to select it all, it demands a WHERE clause.

Also when trying to do this through Kafka Control Center I get a generic error of `An unknown error has occured. Check the connection settings.` when just trying to query it. Also when setting the properties to offset to be earliest here I get the same error, and so that is not of any kind of real help either.

### Additional Info

KSQL Server : confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.2.4
Kafka Broker: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:6.1.0
Zookeeper: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.0

So any kind of point into the right direction would be appreciated, as I do need these queries to always start from the beginning.

Comment: The error seems to suggest your `ksql-cli` is not properly connected to the server

Comment: Though why would creation of the stream and everything else work as proper including the listing of properties?

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to figure it out what was happening. Seems that with the `KSQL-CLI` wasnt working as expected as I had all these set up with docker. Perhaps its because its a docker instances vs an installation but I had to set the following.

I have everything running using the helm charts (https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts) and had to add in several lines when it came to `cp-ksql-server`. The following was added:

```yaml
configurationOverrides:
    "replication.factor": "1"
    "ksql.connect.url": "http://[kafka connect url]:8083"
    "ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
    "ksql.query.pull.table.scan.enabled": "true"
```

The `ksql.connect.url` and `ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset` wouldnt allow me to set it manually, as it seemed it had to be done via start up. So adding them in and updating the helm char allowed me to follow the directions from before.

Comment: Unless you're running create connector queries, you don't need the connect url